# Jquery, ajax, load, ready

Tags: ajax, document-ready

```
$(function(){    
       $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#demo_content').html('<img src="http://v.com/ajax-loader-1.gif"alt="Wait" />');

        $('#demo_content').load('http://vbizmarketing.com/myphp.php?nice=9176198');
        return false;
        cache:false

    });
});
```

This works wonders, and I am gratefull for the stackover flow community helping me with the original problem, But I have been trying to call the

$('#demo_content').html('IMAGE HERE');

in a separate div so that I can have the loading image be centered and not be placed into the left aligned text that I am actually pulling from another file.

Any suggestions or advice is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have a longhand document.ready function nested inside of a shorthand version?

Comment: I honestly cannot provide a logical answer to your question, I am new to ajax and JavaScript and the script above worked

Comment: It will work, but get rid of the `$(document).ready(function() {` code. You just need the `$(function(){` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean just a css rule to center the image?

> in a separate div so that I can have
>   the loading image be centered and not
>   be placed into the left aligned text
>   that I am actually pulling from
>   another file.

You can do it with some css and a call back on the `.load()`

The css:

```
#loading{
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="demo_content">
    <div id="loading">
        <img src="http://vbizmarketing.com/ajax-loader-1.gif"alt="Wait" />
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

The script.

```
$(function() {
    $("#loading").show(); //show the loading div.

    $('#content').load('http://vbizmarketing.com/myphp.php?nice=9176198', function() {
        $("#loading").hide(); //use the callback function for the load method to hide the loading div
    });
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/NMdvs/1/).**

Comment: @Mark- My goal is allow for the 'loading image' to be centered, and once it is done loading then use the loaded content and place it into separate divs. Because right now the loading bar works, and everything is fine, its just I cannot figure out how to place the loading image into a different div and once it is done loading disappear

Comment: I think I am going to implement .ajaxStop()

Comment: See update, you can also use the callback to the `load()` method to hide the div as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of unclear what you're trying to accomplish / having problems with. But in a scenario like this - I've done the following:

```
function loadImage()
{
    $('div#container')
        .html(  "<img class='spinner' src='" + ajax spinner path + "'/>"  )
        .fadeIn();

    var newImg = new Image();
    $(newImg)
        .load( function()
            {
                $('div#container')
                    .stop()
                    .css({
                        'opacity'   :'1.0'
                    })
                    .html(newImg);

                $(this)
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn();
            }
         )
        .attr(  'src'   , ' new image path here ' )
        .error( function()
            {
                $('div#container')
                .html( "<img src='" + loadFailUrl+ "'/>" )
            }
        );
}
```

So - first append the container div with .html. This will be the path to the loading graphic.

The second portion of the function creates a new Image element, attaches a load event, and an error event. Appending the src .attr defines the src path, and initiates the load.

The load event has an anonymous callback function included, which calls stop on the current fadeIn() animation, if its running, and appends the html with the newly created image (at the same time removing the loading graphic).

Finally, the image gets a fadeIn() sequence.

There's only about 17,233 ways of doing this. I've successfully used this in the past...

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div").ajaxStop(function(){  
    $(this).hide();  
});
```

This function hides the loading bar once the content is loaded
Thanks for all the advice.